# Accessing documents on iManage

Tags: python, command-line-interface, imanage

I've searched StackOverflow for an answer to this question, however many of the answers are from years ago.

I am looking to automate a document perusal task which requires accessing documents on iManage Filesite then collating the docs into a folder. I cannot seem to find any documentation about accessing iManage using Python or CLI (most that I'm familiar with). I'm aware of this library

[docs oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E10316_01/ContentIntegration/javadoc/com/stellent/cis/client/command/ICommand.html)

But I'm quite new to Java atm.

Has anyone used any of the above languages to query docs stored on iManage? I note that you can make SQL queries, but I'm still looking for a way to access the querying function using Python, API or CLI

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The iManage Filesite system comes with a full API to allow access to documents, but it is a licence-able product. If you haven't already got access to the SDK you need to speak to your iManage account manager.

IManage Work Server 10 and greater come with a REST based API which can be used to easily download documents from most script languages. There is also a classic COM based API which can be used from .NET or other COM aware languages.

There are examples on the IManage support site @ https://help.imanage.com/hc/en-us on how to access documents through both APIs. If you do have a licence for the SDK and it's installed on your Work Server 10 environment you can inspect the APIs online at https://YOURSERVER/api-docs/v2/#/docs/summary

Comment: Amazing -- thanks a lot for this. I'm going to try this out today.

Comment: any change you would be willing to share API specs with me?

Answer (score 1):

You're definitely going to want to get ahold of Postman and then also download from iManage the pre-packaged list of REST commands that it provides for Postman.

Also familiarize yourself with the IMCC. The iManage Control Center. Within the control center you'll establish Application instances you'd like to give/allow access to your iManage server.  You'll need the ClientID value from that screen when you are making your REST calls initially to acquire an Authorization token.

Also... there is a Refresh token that it does not return by default. Currently they do not have a place within the UI to enable/disable returning the Refresh token.  To enable this, you make a REST call to :

```
PUT https://{your server name}/api/v2/customers/1/settings/{the clientID of your application instance}/oauth2.tokens
```

And the "Body" tab in Postman you add the following:

```json
{
  "type": "value",
  "value": {
    "allow_refresh_token": true,
    "refresh_token_expiry": 14,
    "access_token_max_idle_time": 30
  }
}
```

In the Headers tab, you must have an `X-Auth-Token` parameter specified in order to make this call.

I seem to recall that you need to have the refresh token part enabled if you want to create cacheable sessions.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a sample document download code iManage help portal in written in Powershell and Python using REST API 2.0.

Note: Please do not use COM API as it is reaching EOL on 29 Dec 2023.

https://help.imanage.com/hc/en-us/articles/360012262574-Downloading-a-document

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33763619)

Comment: I can't paste full details here as the info present in above article is proprietary property of product vendor. So I am not sure whether I can simply copy and paste actual details.